# cleartool format string for displaying hyperlinks

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Is there a cleartool describe format string or any other command that will print only the hyperlinks from an object? Like:

```
cleartool describe -long -ahlink -all vob:\MyVOB
```

but without the leading information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the formatted describe, as long as you're not dealing with > 150K of hyperlink data per version, you get the hyperlinks:

> [brian@bullwinkle bcowan-testvob1]$ cleartool desc -fmt "%n\t%[hlink:TextType]p\n" .@@/main/0
>   .@@/main/0    "TextType@2@/vobs/bcowan-testvob1" -> "foobar"

And without the filter (another element):

> [brian@bullwinkle bc-linuxtest]$ cleartool desc -fmt "%n\t%[hlink]p\n" /view/bc-linuxtest/vobs/bc-linuxtest/.@@/main/foo/2
>   /view/bc-linuxtest/vobs/bc-linuxtest/.@@/main/foo/2   "Merge@2@/vobs/bc-linuxtest" <- "/view/bc-linuxtest/vobs/bc-linuxtest/.@@/main/18"

Comment: This returns all the hyperlinks on a single line, so some parsing is required to seperate them.